# How to count null values from multi-columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following data pattern in my SQL 2005 table:

```
MPAN, Date, Reading1, Reading2, Reading3,......, Reading48

134, 21/05/11, , ,0.345 ,......,0.789

134, 22/05/11, , , ,......, 0.467

456, 21/05/11, , , , , 1.234

456, 22/05/11, 0.009 , , 0.534,......

223, 21/05/11, , , ,........, 3.345

223, 22/05/11, 3.223, 1.234, , , ....,0.989
```

For each record row there are differnt number of fields having missing data. How could I find out how many fileds have data missing for each row (group by MPAN and Date). Have had a search on Google, it seems that people suggests Stored Procedures for a similar case?

Please can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select MPAN,
       Date,
       sum
          (
            case when Reading1 is null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when Reading2 is null then 1 else 0 end +
            case when Reading3 is null then 1 else 0 end
          ) as NullCount
from T
group by MPAN,
         Date
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field_1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN field_2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + ... AS total_nulls,
       COUNT(*) as num_rows
FROM table 
GROUP BY total_nulls;
```

With the grouping and field names from your question:

```
SELECT MPAN, Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Reading1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN Reading2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + ... ) AS total_nulls
FROM table 
GROUP BY MPAN, Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  MPAN,
  Date,
  NullCount = COUNT(*) * 48
    - COUNT(Reading1)
    - COUNT(Reading2)
    - COUNT(Reading3)
    …
    - COUNT(Reading48)
FROM atable
GROUP BY MPAN, Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement to compute the sum:

```
select MPAN, date, sum(null_cnt) from (
  select MPAN, date,
  (case when val1 is null then 1 else 0 end) +
  (case when val2 is null then 1 else 0 end) + ...
  (case when val48 is null then 1 else 0 end) null_cnt
  from ...
) group by MPAN, date
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'd have to do something ugly like

```
select MPAN, Date, (
    CASE WHEN Reading1 is null then 1 else 0 end +
    CASE WHEN Reading2 is null then 1 else 0 end +
    CASE WHEN Reading3 is null then 1 else 0 end +
    CASE WHEN Reading4 is null then 1 else 0 end +
    ... +
    CASE WHEN Reading48 is null then 1 else 0 end
) as CountOfNulls

from YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks all for your quick replies. I beleive the CASE function should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the schema, the first thing I would do is break this up into three tables:

'Readings' with an ID and an Name, values like

```
ID  Name
1   Reading1
2   Reading2
...
48  Reading48
```

This makes it easy to add more as you undoubtedly will.

Next, a 'MPAN' table with the 'MPAN's with ID, MPAN and date:

```
ID MPAN Date
1  134  21/05/11
2  134  22/05/11
```

And last, a 'Score' table that relates the two and includes the scores with ReadingID, MPANID, and Score:

```
MPANID ReadingID Score
1      3         0.345
1      48        0.789
2      48        0.467
```

Then you can let relational databases do what they do best and leverage the relationships. For example, this query would get all the MPAN's that had a score for Reading2:

```
SELECT MPAN.*, Scores.Score
  FROM MPAN
  JOIN Scores ON Scores.MPANID = MPAN.ID
             AND Scores.ReadingID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS**

```
select 
MPAN, Date,
coalesce(isnull(reading1,0)+isnull(reading2,0)+isnull(reading3,0)+isnull(reading4,0),0) 
from 
tablename
```